# Html page not showing up in .chm built using Sandcastle Help File Builder

Tags: chm, sandcastle

With earlier version of SHFB (1.9.3.0) I am able to add the 'WhatsNew' html page content. The single html file shows up under contents
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDULA.png)

Below is the tag in .shbproj to add the html page

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="WhatsNew.html" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Following are settings that I am using when running with the latest SHFB version.

```html
<HelpFileFormat>HtmlHelp1</HelpFileFormat>
<SyntaxFilters>Standard</SyntaxFilters>
<PresentationStyle>VS2013</PresentationStyle>
<CleanIntermediates>True</CleanIntermediates>
<KeepLogFile>True</KeepLogFile>
<DisableCodeBlockComponent>False</DisableCodeBlockComponent>
```

When built with the latest version of sandcastle help file builder  I am no longer able to add the html page in the chm. I do not see any build errors or any warnings related to the html content. Any idea what I may be missing?

Answer (score 2):

I learned that starting with version 1.7.0.0, the help file builder supports conceptual content. This is similar in nature to additional content in that it allows you to add non-reference content to the help file that will appear in the table of contents.

So instead of adding the HTML files or .topic files that contain HTML, I had to add the conceptual content that has topic files containing Microsoft Assistance Markup Language (MAML). There is a [HtmlToMamlConverter](https://github.com/EWSoftware/HtmlToMamlConverter/releases/tag/v2022.3.12.0) I used to convert the html file to MAML. I added the _ContentLayout.content (this file was generated as an output of the htmlToMamlConverter) file to my .shfbproj. Added the topic (.aml file) by opening the .content file in Sandcastle GUI. Following are the fields I set

[ContentLayout.Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYVBp.png)